# Showing gridline at value 0 only

Tags: reporting-services, bubble-chart, gridlines

I am having bubble graph which shows two values:

1. YTD position
2. % growth from previous year

Both sets of values are ranging from negative to positive.

I would like to show gridlines (horizontal and vertical) only at value 0, so I have bubbles in 4 quadrants.

I have tried in "visibility" of the gridlines, but  it didn't work:

`iif(Fields!YTD_Actual.Value=0,"True","False")`

Another option would be to differently format gridlines, but it didn't work either.

Comment: You may be simply setting the wrong values... Typically when you set the visibility in SSRS, you're actually setting the `Hidden` value -- i.e. the true value means that the item gets hidden.  I think if you reverse the True and False, it may work as intended.

Comment: which ever way I compose expression I am getting either all visible, or all hidden

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the report in design view?  Where exactly are you setting the visibility?  Is `YTD_Actual` a numeric field?

Comment: I am unable to add screenshot. When I select window "Major Gridlines Properties", "Visibility", then there are change display options - Show, Hide, Show or hide based on expression ==> there I am setting the visibility